# Copied named range are not found

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, named-ranges

I try to duplicate a sheet containing named ranges, and modify the values of some of the named ranges in the new sheet within one module (or pressing only one button widget). The duplication part works normally, but then the duplicated named ranges cannot be found until the run ends.

```
Private Sub MyCode()

  Dim newName As String

  On Error Resume Next
  newName = "sheet2"

  If newName <> "" Then
    Sheets("sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets("sheet1")
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
  End If
  
  Range(newName + "!myRangeName") = newValue
End Sub
```

The names are defined on a sheet-level, and the Calculation is enabled.

I put emphasis on the fact that running :

```
Private Sub MyCode1()

  Dim newName As String

  On Error Resume Next
  newName = "sheet2"

  If newName <> "" Then
    Sheets("sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets("sheet1")
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
  End If
End Sub
```

and then

```
Private Sub MyCode2()
  Range("sheet2" + "!myRangeName") = newValue
End Sub
```

does achieve to copy the sheet and change the named plage's value.

Comment: `newName = sheet2` would always return an empty string surely?  You're trying to set a worksheet object to a string which will throw an "Object doesn't support this method" error, but you tell it to ignore all errors so `newName` is left as an empty string instead.

Comment: sheet2 is in the example supposed to be a string. I edit my post replacing sheet2 by "sheet2".